# How to split a snowman shaped contour into two circles

Tags: python, opencv, contour

### Problem

I am processing an iPhone screen recording of a game automatic replay called Chinese Chess (I press the *play* button once, it automatically goes through all the moves). The screen recording is in 30FPS, and conveniently, every second (30 frames), a new move is made.

For example, the 120th frame looks like this:
[image]

30 frames (1 second) later, the 150th frame looks like this:
[image]

I want to detect each move played by comparing the previous frame to the current frame. My code works if the piece moves more than one square, but if it only moves one square (like in this example above), the 2 contours get merged together (looks like a snowman):
[image]
(Please ignore the rectangles)

This is what I actually want:
[image]

Two separate, circular contours, indicating the **original square of the piece** and the **new square of the piece**.

Note that, because of the shadow and the white ring, the **contour for the new square is bigger than the original square** This is important because it allows me to identify the contours using `cv2.contourArea`

### Code

```py
#previous_frame and current_frame are frames from cv2.VideoCapture()
imageA = previous_frame #the original square
imageB = current_frame #the new square

grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Structural Similarity Index (SSIM)
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #I am using openCV4

cnts.sort(key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) #sort by decreasing order of size
cv2.drawContours(imageB, cnts, 0, (0,0,255), 10) #new coordinate is the largest contour, hence index 0
cv2.drawContours(imageA, cnts, 1, (0,0,255), 10) #original is second largest, hence index 1
```

I have tried using `approxPolyDP` and `minEnclosingCircle` but no luck.

Comment: You can take a look at the [watershed algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html), this seems like the perfect candidate for your problem...

Comment: @SebastianLiendo I took a look at the documentation, and it does indeed seem like the perfect algorithm, but the example showed the use case for a single image. In my case, would I apply the algorithm on the *diff* image or the *thresh* image? (I'm assuming it's the thresh but comparing the thresh code on the example with mine, it's slightly different...)

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to adapt it a little bit. But from what I'm understanding is that you're taking the difference between two images. From there you can binarize the diff image using some kind of threshold. That's where the snowman contour is coming from, and from that binarized image you can then use the watershed algorithm. Could you perhaps upload an image of the thresh, so we can check how it is different?

Comment: I have still difficulty to understand the problem. "*by comparing the previous frame to the current frame*"  may not be a good choice many times. You can try to use [Template-Matching](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)  because your samples seem okey to use it

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk My apologies, I did not mean *"comparing the previous frame to the current frame"*, I meant to say *"comparing the previous move with the current move*".

Since each move is separated by 30 frames, if a game lasts 40 moves for example, it will only make around 40 comparisons.

I did try template matching, but it did not do what I needed it to do.

Comment: precompute the size of the stones once and compare the contour size to it, to find whether they are 1 or 2 or more stones...